# How to partially reshape an xarray

Tags: python, dataset, reshape, python-xarray

I have a DataArray (Xarray) that has 4 coordinates: times, longitude, latitude and variable. Every data is taken monthly, so for each variable I have a different value every month for 83 years. Then, the dimensions of my DataArray are (996, 360, 81, 3), where 996 = 12 * 83.
I need to aggregate the data yearly, but without a mean. In other word, I need to reshape the xarray into a new dimension (83, 360, 81, 36) so that I have a point for every year. It is important that the coordinates that regard longitude and latitude do not change at all.
How can I do this?

I have already tried to use np.reshape() on the ds.values with lack of success.

Comment: please add more details: what have you tried? Also, what is the last dimension?

Comment: The last dimension is a vector containing the values of my variables (temperature, wind speed, relative vorticity).

Comment: What have you tried so far?